# I have a file with this data

Tags: python, string, string-parsing, group-by

**2012-05-10 BRAD 10**
  **2012-05-08 BRAD 40**
  **2012-05-08 BRAD 60**
  **2012-05-12 TOM 100**
   I wanted an output as
  **2012-05-08 BRAD|2|100**
  **2012-05-10 BRAD|1|10**
  **2012-05-12 TOM|1|100**

i started with this code::

```
import os,sys
fo=open("meawoo.txt","w")
f=open("test.txt","r")
fn=f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in fn:
    line = line.strip()
    sline = line.split("|")
    p = sline[1].split(" ")[0],sline[2],sline[4]
    print p
    fo.writelines(str(p)+"\n")
fo.close()
o_read = open("meawoo.txt","r")
x_read=o_read.readlines()
from operator import itemgetter
x_read.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
from itertools import groupby
z = groupby(x_read, itemgetter(0))
print z
for elt, items in groupby(x_read, itemgetter(0)):
    print elt, items
    for i in items:
        print i

It will be very helpful if u suggest me some usefull changes to my work.TIA
```

Comment: Give a more accurate description in words of what you are trying to accomplish. Also you say you have one file but your code opens two files.

Comment: Just tell me if i have a file with data as::
    2012-05-10 BRAD 6    
    2012-05-10 BRAD 4  
    2012-05-08 BRAD 20  
    How would i get this::  
    2012-05-08  
    BRAD|1|20  
    2012-05-10  
    BRAD|2|10  
    i.e Groupby DATE  
    Groupby NAME|Len(NAME)|SUM(VALUES)

Answer (score 3):

The following code should print the data in your wanted format (as far as I understand it):

```
d = {}
with open("testdata.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        if parts[0] in d:
            if parts[1] in d[parts[0]]:
                d[parts[0]][parts[1]][0] += int(parts[2])
            else:
                d[parts[0]][parts[1]] = [int(parts[2]), 0]
            d[parts[0]][parts[1]][1] +=1
        else:
            d[parts[0]] = {parts[1]: [int(parts[2]), 1]}
    for date in sorted(d):
        for name in sorted(d[date]):
            print "%s %s|%d|%d" % (date, name, d[date][name][0], d[date][name][1])
```

I save every line in a dictionary with the lines' dates as keys, and the value is another dictionary with the name as the key and the value is a list with two elements: The first is the cumulative sum of the numbers of this name on this date up to this line, and the second is the number of summands for this date/name constellation. I then print the dictionary in your demanded format and use the circumstance that the comparison of two dates gives the same result as the comparison of the dates as strings that have the format `YYY-MM-DD`, so I can just use the `sorted` function on the date strings. I sort on names too.

For an example (adapted to not being able to use a file) see http://ideone.com/rx3h2. It gives the same output you demanded.

Comment: Hi thanks but as i am new to python i just wana ask if it is a file and i have to iterate and then group them then what are the changes you would suggest me.

Comment: The code above should work with a file with a name `testdata`.

Comment: Hey check with adding one more line in the file and u will find something new:: add this line :: 
     2012-05-10 SIM 100

Comment: @Abhineet 50 Shades of Python :)

Comment: @halex +1 for your patience mate.